# Python 2.7 on raspberry pi 3...... os.system calls blocking interrupts?

Tags: python-2.7, interrupt, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I'm quite a newbie in python (though not so newbie on programming & IT in general) so please forgive me if I'm going to ask something trivial...

I have the following setup:

- a Raspberry PI 3 with a Wheezy Raspbian distro running on it (or so I think, it is the PiMusicBox image from pimusicbox.com, should be Wheezy based from what I red on the docs). Python version is 2.7.3.
- a mechanical rotary encoder connected as follows (pin numbers are referred to  BOARD pins):

  - Ground to ground pin 39 (ground, this is easy :-) )
  - "+" to pin 1 (3.3 V, another easy one)
  - dt to pin 13
  - clk to pin 15

The behavior of the following sample piece of code is not really explicable to me (I suppose is independent from the specific kind of input):

```
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

TunerDtPin = 13    #  dt pin
TunerClkPin = 15    #  clk pin

last_state=0

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)    
    GPIO.setup(TunerDtPin, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)    
    GPIO.setup(TunerClkPin, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(TunerClkPin, GPIO.BOTH, callback=rotary_callback) 

def rotary_callback(pin):
    global last_state
    sig = GPIO.input(TunerDtPin)
    clk = GPIO.input(TunerClkPin)
    if (clk and clk!=last_state):
        if(clk!=sig): 
            print 1
        else: 
            print -1
    last_state=clk

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()             # Release resource   

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program start from here
    setup()
    try:
        while True:
            os.system("uptime")
            time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  
        destroy()
```

The callback function is NEVER called...the script just keeps printing the 'uptime' call output every ten seconds.

BUT, if leave out the system call in the script (commenting the row is enough) the whole things works like a charm printing '1' or '-1', depending on rotation direction, for each encoder step....am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like I didn't search enough in the docs....

The subprocess module is around from a while... https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Replacing `os.system("uptime")` with `subprocess.call("uptime")` did the trick.